# Would anyone know the source of this error in mediawiki?

Tags: smtp, mediawiki

> Error sending mail: authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response
>   code received from server (code: 535, response: Authentication
>   credentials invalid)]

Comment: The source is an invalid credentials as the error says.

Comment: Authentication credentials invalid means user and/or password incorrect.

Comment: I meant is there a particular file that requires attention?

Comment: It doesn't reference an exact file. So wanted to know which file/files might be responsible.

Comment: One file that might be part  of it is `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and other files found in the `/etc/postfix` folder if that is the application that is installed to send mail.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error. You need to fill in the credentials in the username and password fills, located in /vendor/mail/Mail/smtp.php. Once this is done, it would be safer to set up an array called $wgSMTP, containing info on the username and password, in LocalSettings.php.